# how to display two different bitmap images in canoe?

Tags: panel, capl, canoe

I would like to display two different images in the panel based on event, example, for light on display one bit map image, And for light off display another bitmap image.
 I already tried to browse the options in properties box there is not much information available regarding this, did anybody have solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use a Switch/Indicator control and use a bitmap that includes all states in one image. See chapter "Assigning and Creating Bitmaps" in the manual.